# No se despliegan correctamente los submenús

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema con mi código ya que estoy tratando de realizar un menú, al seleccionar la opción me debe mandar a otro menú pero se queda en la misma opción y no corre el juego.

Agradecería cualquier aporte.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
struct nodo;

using namespace std;

//portotipos de funciones 
    void MenuPrincipal ();
    void MenuDomino ();
    void MenuUno ();
    void MenuAjedrez ();
    void MenuLoteria ();
//funciones MenuPrincipal
    void Domino ();
    void Uno ();
    void Ajedrez ();
    void Loteria ();
//funciones Menu Domino
    void Nivel1 ();
    void Nivel2 ();
    void Nivel3 ();
    void Salir1 ();
//funciones Menu Uno
    void Reglas1 ();
    void Colores ();
    void Tamanos ();
    void Salir2 ();
//funciones Menu Ajedrez
    void Reglas2 ();
    void Cedes ();
    void Salir3 ();
//funciones Menu Loteria 
    void Cartas ();
    void Historia ();
    void Salir4 ();
int main ()
{
    void MenuPrincipal ();
    return 0;
}
void MenuPrincipal ()
{
    int opcion;
    for (;;)
    bool repetir = true;
    
    do 
    {
        system ("cls");
        
        cout<<"MENU PRINCIPAL... ABRIL AMARO AVENDAÑO"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n1. Domino"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n2. Uno"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n3. Ajedrez"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n4. Loteria"<<endl;
        
        cout<<"Ingrese una opción: ";
        cin>>opcion;
//determinacion de acciones
    
        switch (opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                void MenuDomino();
                break;
            
            case 2:
                void MenuUno ();
                break;
            
            case 3:
                void MenuAjedrez();
                break;
                
            case 4:
                void MenuLoteria();
                break;
            
            case 0:
                repetir = false;
                default:cout<<"opcion no valida";
                //break;
                
            }
            get chc;
        }while (repetir);
    }
    
//definiciones de la funciones 

void MenuDomino ()
{
    int opcion;
    bool repetir = true;
    
    do{
        system("cls");
        
        cout<<"MENU DOMINO"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n1. Nivel1"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n2. Nivel2"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n3. Nivel3"<<endl;
        cout<<"n. Salir"<<endl;
        
        cout<<"Ingrese una opcion: ";
        cin>>opcion;
        
        switch (opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                void Nivel1();
                break;
                
            case 2:
                void Nivel2();
                break;
                
            case 3:
                void Nivel3();
                break;
                
            case 4:
                void Salir1 ();
                break;
                
            case 0:
                repetir = false;
                break; 
            
        }
    }while (repetir);
}
void MenuUno ()
{
    int opcion;
    bool repetir = true;
    
    do
    {
        
        system("cls");
        
        
        cout<<"MENU UNO"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n1. Reglas"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n2. Colores"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n3. Tamaños"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n4. Salir"<<endl;
        
        cout<<"Ingrese una opcion: ";
        cin>>opcion;
        
        switch (opcion)
    {
    case 1:
        void Reglas1 ();
        break;
        
    case 2:
        void Colores ();
        break;
        
    case 3:
        void Tamanos ();
        break;
        
    case 4:
        void Salir2 ();
        break;
        
    case 0:
        repetir = false;
        break;
    }
  }while (repetir); 
}
void MenuAjedrez ()
{
    int opcion;
    bool repetir = true;
    
    do
    {
        
        system ("cls");
        
        cout<<"MENU AJEDREZ"<<endl;
        cout<<"COMPETENCIAS"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n1. Reglas"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n2. Cedes"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n3. Salir"<<endl;
        
        cout<<"Ingrese una opcion: ";
        cin>>opcion;
        
        switch (opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                void Reglas2 ();
                break;
                
            case 2:
                void Cedes ();
                break;
                
            case 3:
                void Salir3 ();
                break;
                
            case 0:
                repetir = false;
                break;
        } 
    }while (repetir);
}
void MenuLoteria ()
{
    int opcion;
    bool repetir = true;
    
    do
    {
        
        system ("cls");
        
        cout<<"MENU LOTERIA"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n1. Cartas"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n2. Historia"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n3. Salir"<<endl;
        
        cout<<"Ingrese una opcion: ";
        cin>>opcion;
        
        switch (opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                void Cartas ();
                break;
                
            case 2:
                void Historia ();
                break;
                
            case 3:
                void Salir4 ();
                break;
                
            case 0:
                repetir = false;
                break;
        }
    }while (repetir); 
}

//return 0;
//}
```

Comment: Tu problema reside en que usas la palabra reservada `void` antes de llamar cualquier menú, estas definiendo un prototipo con ello, no llamando la función. Basta que cada que llames un menú sea solo como `nombreMenu();`

Answer (score 0):

Como te dijo @denso, las funciones se llaman con su nombre y paréntesis con sus parámetros dentro.

Si tienes la siguiente función:

```
void fun(int a, int b){
    ...
}
```

Debes llamarla así:

```
fun(1, 2);
```

Nota que 1 y 2 se pueden cambiar por los números que quieras.

---

El otro problema es que tienes un for que se ejecuta infinitamente en la función `MenuPrincipal`:

```
for (;;)
```

Puedes ver que produce un ciclo infinito [aquí](https://tio.run/##RcixDkAwEIDh/Z7iwlKDXbQxegpLHZpLuErVJJ69yuLb/p/2vabVikupZKH1nGY07I8YZrt18L98WFwHwBJxsyyqugCzxQdUWldfvI44tS35MxqDRe/DIIWGO6UG7EjwAA).